# static variable not incrementing on function calling

Tags: php, static, token

```
function genTokenNo()
{
    static $i=0;
    $i=$i+1;
    return str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

When I calls this function in other file the function doesn't returns unique value (an incremented value). Also while I echo this function in same file(where the function is made) it works fine. 
I know the concept of scope of static variable as I have already tried this by replacing $i by $_SESSION['i'] but no expected result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every time you call genTokenNo() you set $i to 0.

Comment: When i tried your code it will return +1 every time when i call function like `echo genTokenNo(); //00001
echo "<br />";
echo genTokenNo(); //00002
echo "<br />";
echo genTokenNo(); //00003
echo "<br />";
echo genTokenNo(); //00004`

Comment: Yes it shows exactly like this when the function is being called in the file where it is being declared. I want these values in other file.

Comment: Ok, in which file you try to get value of `genTokenNo()`, before call that function you have to include the file in which this function is declare. That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Note the value of `$i` is not persisted. So whenever you run new request to the server, the script is reloaded and `$i` is reset to `0`.

To persist the variable in the per-user session use `$SESSION['i']` but as you already tried, this will be unique per session, not globally.

To have globally unique number you need to store on the disk, using `fopen`/`flock`/`fread`/`fwrite`/`fclose` functions.

Answer (score 0):

For a single request it should work fine -

```
function genTokenNo()
{
    static $i=0;    
    $i=$i+1;
    return str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo genTokenNo() . ' - ' . genTokenNo() . ' - ' . genTokenNo();
```

**Output**

```
00001 - 00002 - 00003
```

But if you are requesting multiple times then the value will be reset on every request and every time the response will be the same. I would suggest to store the value in database or some file. In this case using `seesion` woludn't be reliable.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO table SET TokenNo='".genTokenNo()."';  this is the use of function in secondfile.php. I am trying to store the output in database.

Comment: So I guess they are in different requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure will look like below:

**file1.php**

```
function genTokenNo()
{
    static $i=0;
    $i=$i+1;
    return str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

**file2.php**

```
include('file1.php');
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Include file before call that function.

echo genTokenNo(); //00001
echo "<br />";
echo genTokenNo(); //00002
echo "<br />";
echo genTokenNo(); //00003
echo "<br />";
echo genTokenNo(); //00004
```

Comment: @sadiamallick Can you please you code like i posted in my answer, i mean to say both files code.

Comment: @sadiamallick You posted as answer :), you have to edit your question and put there your updated code. :)

Comment: @sadiamallick, write the query like `$sql = "INSERT INTO table (TokenNo) VALUES('".genTokenNo()."')";`, and check if you get the same result then try to `echo $query; die;` and run the file then in the browser you got the query echoing copy that query and execute it in phpmyadmin "SQL" section. And let me know if any error is displaying in phpmyadmin when you execute same query.

Comment: @sadiamallick And first check, mysql connection is working or not, because in your code i didn't see the connection.....

Comment: Sir am using XAMPP  and connection file is already included. I have shown the part of code where I expect the error would be propagating. Also I am using Xampp so in phpmyadmin my table's column TokenNo is filled with same data i.e. 00001

Answer (score 0):

**file1.php**

```
<?php
    function genTokenNo()
    {
        static $i=0;
        $i=$i+1;
        return str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
include('file1.php');
$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET TokenNo='".genTokenNo()."' ";
mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

> when function exists then lost the value of static variable

```
if(isset($_SESSION['i']))
   $_SESSION['i']++;
else
   $_SESSION['i']=0;
```

Comment: No.. same output 00001.

Comment: that's correct format and replace static variable section used that session variable

Comment: Yes I have tried this but still it gives the same output. 00001

Comment: used for global variable

Comment: $GLOBALS['i']++ used and $i defined into other function